# Passing argument to a flask GET function

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write a simple messaging function and, despite searching, having trouble coming up with a workable solution. On the get function, the code retrieves stored messages and passes this to be rendered.

The post function stores the message which all works fine, however I'm trying to redirect the user back to the original page they came from to display the new message, hence trying to pass the receiving user variable to the get function.

My code so far below. I'm new to flask so would appreciate any other pointers as well. Thanks in advance!

```
@app.route("/messaging", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def messaging():
    if request.method == "GET":

        clicked_user = request.args.get('user')
        messages = db.execute("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (m_sending_user = :self_user AND m_receiving_user = :other_user) OR (m_sending_user = :other_user AND m_receiving_user = :self_user)",
                        self_user = session["user_id"],
                        other_user = clicked_user)

        return render_template("messaging.html", messages=messages, clicked_user=clicked_user)

    if request.method == "POST":

        receiving_user = request.form.get("recipient")

        db.execute("INSERT INTO messages (m_sending_user, m_receiving_user, message) VALUES (:m_sending_user, :m_receiving_user, :message)",
                        m_sending_user = session["user_id"],
                        m_receiving_user = receiving_user,
                        message = request.form.get("reply"))

        flash("Sent!")
        return render_template("messaging.html")
```

Comment: I dont see "'am trying to redirect the user back to the original page they came from" , any redirects in your code. It would help to have the route you are redirecting to as well, as a snippet of your html code, that calls this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not simply have the post function also call the get function like so

```
def get_function(clicked_user):
    messages = db.execute("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (m_sending_user = :self_user AND m_receiving_user = :other_user) OR (m_sending_user = :other_user AND m_receiving_user = :self_user)",
                  self_user = session["user_id"],
                  other_user = clicked_user)

    return render_template("messaging.html", messages=messages, clicked_user=clicked_user)

@app.route("/messaging", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def messaging():
    if request.method == "GET":

        clicked_user = request.args.get('user')

        return get_function(clicked_user)

    if request.method == "POST":

        receiving_user = request.form.get("recipient")

        db.execute("INSERT INTO messages (m_sending_user, m_receiving_user, message) VALUES (:m_sending_user, :m_receiving_user, :message)",
                        m_sending_user = session["user_id"],
                        m_receiving_user = receiving_user,
                        message = request.form.get("reply"))

        flash("Sent!")
        return get_function(m_receiving_user)
```

But of course with better named functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you send data in `GET` request, it will be visible in URL parameter. Rather, you can use `session` object to store variable. More on `session` object can be found in the [official documentation on session object].(https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#sessions)

You can use `url_for` with `redirect` method to redirect user to the original template.

Here I have shown a basic example:

`messaging.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Post request redirect</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

    {% if clicked_user %}
      Clicked user: {{ clicked_user }}
    {% endif %}

    {% if messages %}
      Messages: {{ messages }}
    {% endif %}

    <h3>Send a Message</h3>
    <form action='{{url_for("messaging")}}' method="post">
      Recipient:
      <input type="text" name="recipient">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, request, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
# Set the secret key to some random bytes. Keep this really secret!
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'



@app.route("/messaging", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def messaging():
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = {
            "shovon": "some messages for shovon",
            "arsho": "other messages for arsho"
        }
        receiving_user = None
        messages = None
        if 'receiving_user' in session:
            receiving_user = session["receiving_user"]
        messages = data.get(receiving_user)
        return render_template("messaging.html", messages=messages, clicked_user=receiving_user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        receiving_user = request.form.get("recipient")
        session["receiving_user"] = receiving_user
        flash("Sent!")
        return redirect(url_for("messaging"))
```

**Output:**

- Before form submission:

[image: before form submission]

- After form submission:

[image: after form submission]

N.B.: Here I have mocked the database queries with static dictionary search.